# not able to get effect of modified tcp.cc file in NS2.35 (ubuntu-12.10)

Tags: compilation, makefile, ns2

I have modified tcp.cc file and then in terminal I executed these commands at /ns2.35 directory

```
./configure
make clean
make
make install
```

But in 'make install' I am getting following error:

```
for d in /usr/local/man/man1; do \
        if [ ! -d $d ]; then \
            mkdir -p $d ;\
        fi;\
    done
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 ns /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ns.1 /usr/local/man/man1
```

And I am not getting effect of modified tcp.
while I run 'which ns ' terminal shows '/usr/local/bin/'.
and my downloaded source code is in/home/ns/...
Please tell me how to get rid of this problem...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to after modification of tcp.cc,
run following command in /ns2.35/ directory

```
./configure
make clean
make
make install
```

However I'm getting error, but I ignore it. Then to run any further tcl-scripts I need to go to ~/ns2.35/ directory and I get effect of modified tcp.cc.

Answer (score 0):

Those messages look like perfectly legitimate instructions issued by `make install` to perform the installation (`make` likes to print a log of what it is doing, to aid debugging). They're not wrong, not at all. Indeed, the `/usr/bin/install -c -m 755 ns /usr/local/bin` is the thing that copies the built version of the executable binary (`ns`) into its target location (`/usr/local/bin`) so that it can be run by any user of the system.

Whatever is going wrong, if anything, it's *definitely* not the parts that you have told us in detail. (If it is failing to install, the most likely cause of the problem by far is a failure to elevate your permissions first: often you need `sudo make install` instead of just plain `make install`…)

Comment: Thanks, I am runnning all commands in root. ns2.35 is installed successfully and giving right results when I run tcl-scripts.But after modification of tcp.cc file, changes are not get reflected.

Comment: @nimesh Umm yeah. Installation makes a copy…

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you will get file error when you run make install as you are running as user and the permission will be denied

Just run "sudo make install".

Now all changes will be affected to all files